# :first-child selector not working?

Tags: html, dom, css-selectors

I don't understand why i can't select the first element with class ".adjacent-month" in my cal-week-5 div. (To make a left border on the last day)

http://jsfiddle.net/qqLcyt1h/

HTML :

```
        <div class=" week cal-week-5">
            <div class="day past calendar-day-2015-03-30 calendar-dow-0">30
                <div class=" value val-30"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="day past calendar-day-2015-03-31 calendar-dow-1">31
                <div class=" value val-31"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="day past adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-04-01 calendar-dow-2">1
                <div class=" value val-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

`.cal-week-5 .day .adjacent-month:first-child .value`

1) The cell has *both* the `.day` and the `.adjacent-month` classes, so this will never work.

`.cal-week-5 .day.adjacent-month:first-child .value`

2) The `:first-child` only applies to the first child of the parent element, so this would only fire if the day was the first day of the 5th week.

There's some experimental options for selecting first of types. You can read more here: [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

*However*, I'd suggest modifying your code to add a new class to the first cell. It's a lot easier and more cross-browser compatible. If you don't care about older browsers, you can look at the fancy CSS3 tools.

Comment: Thank you ! Add a new class to the first adjacent-month cell ? And when you're talking avout fancy CSS3 tools, you mean Advanced Selectors ?

Comment: @Anti Yes. Older browsers, particularly Internet Explorer, will not support as many `:selectors` as you'd like, so be careful. I'd suggest adding a new class, like `first-of-next-month`, and applying styles to that directly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Jaw.sh, you would need to remove the `.day` part of the selector.
However, your biggest miscomprehension probably comes from the `:first-child` selector itself.

As explained in the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching), the `:first-child` selector “Matches element E when E is the first child of its parent.”.

This means that `.day .adjacent-month:first-child` matches any element with class `adjacent-month` that is at some level below an element with class `day` and that is the first child of its immediate parent.

For instance, this would be matched:

```
<div class="day">
    <ul>
        <li class="adjacent-month">First child</li>
        <li class="adjacent-month">Second child</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What you probably want here is something like

```
.cal-week-5 :not([class*=adjacent-month]) + .adjacent-month .value
```

documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) and which should be pretty well supported.